# How can I get a specific http header in a compojure request

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I am getting the body and headers from the request like this:

```
(POST "/api/item" {body :body headers :headers} (create-item body headers))
```

The body is wrapped, so I get a keyword map and I can easily take values from the that:

```
(def app
    (-> (handler/api app-routes)
        (middleware/wrap-json-body {:keywords? true})
        (middleware/wrap-json-response)))
```

As simple as:

```
(:item-name body)
```

How can I achieve the same with the headers, or just simply take a specific header value? Do I have to map the headers into a Clojure data structure first?

If I print headers I get something like this:

```
({host localhost:3000, user-agent Mozilla/5.0})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers are already in a Clojure data structure. If you want a better idea of the data types present, use `prn` instead of `println`, and you will see that it is a a hash-map with strings as keys.

`(:foo x)` is a shortcut for `(get x :foo)`. For a hash-map with string keys you can get a value with eg. `(get headers "host")`. There is a function in `clojure.walk`, `clojure.walk/keywordize-keys` that will turn keys of a data structure into keywords, recursively through a nested structure. IMHO this is a bit silly, and one is better off using `get` and the string keys in most cases.

Comment: I've been able to arrive at the solution now, thanks. It turned out that I needed `(get (first headers) "host")` because headers comes in a `ArraySeq`.